# How to use the angular material theme?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I made a seed project for Angular Material and want to check out some of the features the framework offers. My HTML is working fine and some other `ng` actions are also working well.

When I tried to check the form feature, the page renders but the theme and other actions are not working. I am referring to [Angular Material `input` demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input) as I explore the form feature. I have included the theme module but it's not working.

**Module.js**

```
var app = angular.module('Tool', ["ng","ngAnimate","ngAria", 'ngMaterial','ngMessages', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource','ngRoute', 'satellizer', 'myConfig.config'])
    .config(function($authProvider,$mdThemingProvider) {
        $authProvider.google({
            clientId: 'XXXXXX',
            url: '/auth/google',
            authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
            redirectUri: "http://localhost:8585" || window.location.origin || window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host,
            requiredUrlParams: ['scope'],
            optionalUrlParams: ['display'],
            scope: ['profile', 'email'],
            scopePrefix: 'openid',
            scopeDelimiter: ' ',
            display: 'popup',
            type: '2.0',
            popupOptions: { width: 452, height: 633 }
        });

        $mdThemingProvider.theme('docs-dark', 'default')
        .primaryPalette('yellow')
        .dark();

    });
```

**Route.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Route configuration.
 */
angular.module('Tool').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        // For unmatched routes
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        // Application routes
        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'templates/newpage.html'
            })

    }
]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Tool">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tool</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Welcome to new Tool
</h1>

<md-button class="md-primary">Click me</md-button>
<md-button class="md-accent">or maybe me</md-button>
<md-button class="md-warn">Careful</md-button>

<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" layout="column">
  <md-content md-theme="docs-dark" layout-padding layout="row" layout-sm="column">
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Title</label>
      <input ng-model="user.title">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Email</label>
      <input ng-model="user.email" type="email">
    </md-input-container>
  </md-content>
  <md-content layout-padding>
    <form name="userForm">
      <div layout layout-sm="column">
        <md-input-container style="width:80%">
            <label>Company (Disabled)</label>
            <input ng-model="user.company" disabled>
          </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Submission Date</label>
          <input type="date" ng-model="user.submissionDate">
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
      <div layout layout-sm="column">
        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>First name</label>
          <input ng-model="user.firstName">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input ng-model="theMax">
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
      <md-input-container flex>
        <label>Address</label>
        <input ng-model="user.address">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container md-no-float>
        <input ng-model="user.address2" placeholder="Address 2">
      </md-input-container>
      <div layout layout-sm="column">
        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>City</label>
          <input ng-model="user.city">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>State</label>
          <input ng-model="user.state">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Postal Code</label>
          <input ng-model="user.postalCode">
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
      <md-input-container flex>
        <label>Biography</label>
        <textarea ng-model="user.biography" columns="1" md-maxlength="150"></textarea>
      </md-input-container>
    </form>
  </md-content>
</div>


<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade
    your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->

<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>
</html>
```

**democtrl.js**

/**
 * Demo Controller
 */

```
angular.module('Tool','ngMaterial','ngMessages')
    .controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', DemoCtrl]);

function DemoCtrl($scope) {
$scope.user = {
      title: 'Developer',
      email: 'ipsum@lorem.com',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '' ,
      company: 'Google' ,
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy' ,
      city: 'Mountain View' ,
      state: 'CA' ,
      biography: 'Loves kittens, snowboarding, and can type at 130 WPM.\n\nAnd rumor has it she bouldered up Castle Craig!',
      postalCode : '94043'
    };

}
```

**bower.json**

```
{
    "name": "angular-material",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "An AngularJS implementation of the responsive dashboard",
    "main": "index.html",
    "license": "MIT",
    "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "test",
        "tests"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "angular-cookies": "~1.2.21",
        "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.10",
        "font-awesome": "~4.1.0",
        "angular-resource":  "~1.3.0",
        "angular": "^1.4.6",
        "angular-animate": "^1.4.6",
        "angular-aria": "^1.4.6",
        "angular-material": "^0.11.2",
        "angular-route": "~1.3.*",
        "gulp-ng-config": "~1.2.1",
        "angular-animate": "^1.4.6",
        "satellizer": "~0.12.5"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "xxx"
    },
      "devDependencies": {
    "angular-material": "xxx"
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to specify an accent palette? `$mdThemingProvider.theme('xxxxxx', 'default')
                .primaryPalette('blue')
                .accentPalette('orange')`

Comment: The css build was not taking the css, so I just update the .bowerrc as :   "directory": "src/components/", earlier it was missing and it worked but some features still missing. Working on it  will update when it's done.

Comment: From what I see (in index.html), you are declaring the md-theme="docs-theme" for mdContent, but your mdButtons with theme classes md-primary/md-accent/md-warn reside outside that declaration. Try putting them inside? Also, keep in mind that not all AM components support theming (see https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/02_declarative_syntax).

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming the problem is coming from the buttons not being themed. If that is the problem, the theme you configured is not the default theme; it is the "docs-dark" theme and will only be used in `md-content` blocks it is assigned to.

You can configure the default theme like so:

Module.js

```
'use strict'

var app = angular.module('Tool', ["ng","ngAnimate","ngAria",
  'ngMaterial','ngMessages', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies','ngResource','ngRoute',
  'satellizer', 'myConfig.config'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('yellow') // I like green, but just me
    .dark(); // Dark is pretty cool.
```

Now the `.dark()` and `.primaryPalette('yellow')` will be applied globally.

Comment: The authProvider is not necessary.